# In LWC how would I get the record types of an Object based on the users Permissions?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, record-type, getobjectinfo

Utilising `getObjectInfo` to obtain the record types I notice Master in the list, I presume then this is getting all the record types regardless of the users permissions.

If this is the case how would I get the record types the user can see?

If this is not the case how would I remove the master record type from the list?

Additionally is it then possible to get the picklist values in LWC based on those record types?

Comment: The "data" that is returned from the getObjectInfo wire contains  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_responses_object_info.htm -- which contains "recordTypeInfos" - which contains https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_responses_record_type_info.htm#ui_api_responses_record_type_info which has an "available" flag you can check to see if the record type is available to the user.  (Sorry don't have time to compose this into a full answer right now.)